# Find id of control when onKeyup event call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find id of input control. 
Here is the HTML CODE.

```
<div id="product">
    <div class="inputHolderOrder">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 2px;">Product Name</p>

        <input type="text" id="pro_data_0" class="inputRight pro input_wid" name="product_name[]" style="" onkeyup="productSearch('1');" >

        <div id="idProduct_0" class="proSea" style="position: absolute;z-index: 111111111111;background: #fff;">       

        </div>                         
    </div>
```

Here id will dynamically generate on foreach loop. 
IDs will be like
"pro_data_0, pro_data_1, pro_data_2, pro_data_3".

Here is my Javascript code.

```
function productSearch(pagev){
    $("#product").find("input").on('input', function () {
        var idname = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(idname);
        var input_data = $('#'+idname).val();
        console.log(input_data);
    });
}
```

It's return id first time, but not second time.

I use `.find('input')` to find control which I type text.

Comment: How an when are you calling `productSearch()`? Where is the element `#product`?

Comment: @yogesh - Why did you undo all the edits?

Comment: This is id my mistake. edit that

Comment: your `#product` is a class `.product`

Comment: @PatricioVargas - The OP have updated the code.

Comment: It's id which fixed. not change it . just input changes on loop

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for the update my friend

Comment: For future reference, only add relevant tags. This question has nothing to do with PHP or CodeIgniter.

Comment: ok brother. thanx for advise

Comment: @MAHABUBHOSSAINRISHAD  did you checked my recent edited solution?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery, so simplified your code like this:-

HTML (no need to do `onkeyup="productSearch('1');")`:

```
<div id="product">
  <div class="inputHolderOrder">
    <p style="margin-bottom: 2px;">Product Name</p>

    <input type="text" id="pro_data_0" class="inputRight pro input_wid" name="product_name[]" style="">

    <div id="idProduct_0" class="proSea" style="position: absolute;z-index: 111111111111;background: #fff;">

    </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#product input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    var idname = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(idname);
    var input_data = $(this).val();
    console.log(input_data);
  })
});
```

Output:-https://jsfiddle.net/y93ajrtm/  And https://jsfiddle.net/7q9xu1eg/

Note:- Make sure jQuery library added before your script code

Answer (score 2):

Change onkeyup event with `this` parameter

```
onkeyup="productSearch('1', this);"
```

Change onkeyup function as below

```
function productSearch(pagev, control){
        var idname = control.id;
        console.log(idname);
        var input_data = control.value;
        console.log(input_data);
}
```

Might this will help.